# Multiple @ConditionalOnMissingBean bean which will be used

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have multiple  bean be annotated with @ConditionalOnMissingBean, which will be used? How can i control the priority?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control `@Bean` creation ordering, you can use the annotation `@Order`

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class First {

    public int first() {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Component
@Order(2)
public class Second {

    public int second() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Or you can also use `@DependsOn`

```
@Configuration
public class ActionCfg {
 
    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"actionA","actionB"})
    public ActionC actionC(){
        return new ActionC();
    }
    
    @Bean("ActionA")
    public ActionA actionA() {
        return new ActionA();
    }
    
    @Bean("ActionB")
    public ActionB actionB() {
        return new ActionB();
    }   
}
```

`ActionA` and `ActionB` will initialized before `ActionC`.

Answer (score 0):

The bean whose auto-configuration class is run first will be taken.

There is `@AutoConfigureBefore`, `@AutoConfigureAfter` and `@AutoConfigureOrder` to control the order of auto-configuration classes.

Comment: so which auto-configuration class is run first if i do not use @Order? how do spring decide the order by default?